# Jenkins can't find "Git plugin"

Tags: jenkins

In Plugin Manager, under the Available tab, "Git plugin" is not available.

I'm running the Jenkins war with Tomcat.

Can I paste a log, a config or something? This problem was detailed elsewhere, can't find link but everyone had success there with "setting up a proxy". How do I satisfy Jenkins so  I can get git installed?

Answer (score 0):

The git plugin is one of the default plugins.

You should see it already installed if you look under the "Installed" tab.

Comment: But theres not Git under Source Code Management. It just says None.

Answer (score 0):

Git is no longer installed by default (as of 2.2xx (?)).

Also pluginManager "Available" tab no longer lists all plugins by default - use Search box on plugin page. Search for "git".

If you need a proxy set, it's under the Advanced tab.